# Organizing R's work in functions and subfuctions

Tags: r, function, matlab

My aim is to better organize the work done by a R code.

In particular it could be useful to split the R code I have written in different R files, perhaps with each R file accomplishing to a different task. I have in mind what we can do in Matlab with different M files, where we can easily call functions written in different M files directly from the main code.

Is it useful to write this R files in the form of functions? 
How can we call these R files /functions in the main code?

Thanks

Comment: To call code from a file you use the `source` command. Sufficiently complicated and frequently used functions and classes can be put together into a package and then loaded. To do so is outside my field of knowledge, however.

Comment: Building a package is not nearly as complicated as it can seem at first, particularly if you are using the latest version of RStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you intend to write an R package, you should rethink your organization.  R is **not** Matlab, thank goodness!   You can place as many functions as you wish into a single file, and make them all available in your environment with  `source foo.r` .  If you are writing a collection of generic functions and don't want to build a package, this really is the cleaner way to go.
As a side thought, consider making some of your tools more flexible by adding more input arguments.  You may find that you don't really need so many separate functions/files.  As a trivial example, if you have some function `do_it_double` , another `do_it_integer` , and yet another `do_it_character` , all of which do basically the same thing, just merge them into a single `do_it_all(x,y,datatype='double')`  and override the default datatype as desired. (I know this can be done with internal input validation. I'm just giving an example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use source("filename.R") to include the file in your main script.

I am not sure if there is a ready function to include an entire directory, but it is straightforward to write using list.files() and then call source dynamicly for each filename. You can also filter files to only list *.R for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach might be working good. I would recommend to wrap the code in a function and use one R file for one R function.

It might be interesting to look at the packages [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) and [ProjectTemplate](http://projecttemplate.net/getting_started.html) which aim to help organizing R code.

Comment: Why one R file per function? Seems cumbersome.

Comment: This is my personal taste. It is easier for me to find the code for a function this way.

Comment: One R file per function may work slightly better with version control tools such as `git`, which have some granularity at the level of files (although they do deal reasonably well with merging within-file differences)